# Show frames per second on desktop?

Tags: framerate

I use Ubuntu 17.10 with KDE Plasma 5 installed and I'd like to show the frames per second. A simple counter of any kind would suffice. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: I found this in another post, but I am not able to validate it myself, but does this work?  `System Settings > Desktop Effects > All Effects > Show FPS`

Comment: @Terrance Cheers, this is what I was looking for. It doesn't look pretty, but it does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered in the comment section by @Terrance:

> I found this in another post, but I am not able to validate it myself,
>   but does this work? System Settings > Desktop Effects > All Effects >
>   Show FPS