# How can I fix KDE compositing at a low framerate?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kwin, framerate

For some reason KDE is really slow this morning. Even the mouse lags as it moves around the screen (clearly not 60fps) and all the animations are jerky. `top` doesn't show anything maxing out the cpu. I've tried changing compositor settings (e.g. using OpenGL) and disabling effects. Also restarting the shell and kwin:

```
nohup kwin --replace &
killall plasmashell ; kstart plasmashell
```

Nothing has helped help. I enabled the FPS meter ([Show frames per second on desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987920/show-frames-per-second-on-desktop)) and rather strangely it is stuck at exactly 24fps. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out that the display had somehow been reset to 24hz, not 60hz after a reboot (only thing I had changed was adding another monitor).

Answer: Double check "Refresh rate" in System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Display Configuration.

Alt: (If using an Nvidia card and drivers are installed) run `nvidia-settings` and check the refresh rate there.